# Holidays falling under 2 week resignation?

Tags: job-change, resignation

I've currently received a job offer from another company and am figured out when to put in my two weeks at my current position.

At my current job, we have holiday pay/days off for Dec 23rd,Dec 26th and Jan 2nd.
If I put in my two weeks today or tomorrow, my 2 week period will include all of these dates.

Being in California, would I be entitled to having these days paid out to me or should I wait till after the holidays to put in my resignation? My new employer has some flexibility of when I can accept the offer.

Answer (score 5):

It is company specific how they would handle this but you would be working after the Christmas holiday, so likely that would be paid. However, Many companies would ask you to make DEc 30th your last day and not pay for the Jan 2 holiday. As that is a new month and New Year, they might not want to have to deal with benefits for one day which is a holiday. Depending on teh the health insurance situation at your new employer, you may want to give notice after the new year just to make sure you have health insurance in Jan.

Answer (score 3):

I would turn it in after the holidays if your new employer is offering that flexibility.  This way its a clean break from your current employer with Holiday pay, and you don't start your new gig while some may be out on an extended holiday break.

Answer (score 1):

This is company dependant. Hand your notice in and your HR dept will give you your end date. If they are days which the company make you take out of your allowance, then they do count (I think).

I wouldn't delay it, the worst that will happen is that they don't count and your start date is some time in January.

Answer (score -1):

If you do want these days paied and you don't want vacation resign now. This might hurt your current employer.

If I were in your shoes I would accept the offer and put a starting date at the 16th of January and give a heads up to the current employer of 3 weeks at least so he could replace me easily.